# how to query attendee with filter duplicate record

Tags: postgresql

i want to query attendee table based on date range. The existing system enables user to checkin or checkout multiple times each day. Now the problem is, how to get the data which is filtered, where for each day i get first checkin timestamp, and last checkout timestamp per user ID.

Here are the screenshots :

[current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfC26.png)

expected result :

[extected data (get latest checkout each day per user ID)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b0yQ.png)

FYI, i am using postgresql 9.6 with PgAdmin4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't add images as sample data. This makes it hard for us the reproduce your problem. Please add the data and expected output as copyable text or provide a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c39cbaacb8270b15b0076203b89c94a)

```
SELECT
    createdby,
    check_date::date,                                                    
    MIN(check_date) as check_in,       -- 2
    MAX(check_date) as check_out
FROM mytable
GROUP BY createdby, check_date::date   -- 1
```

1. Group by your user (I guess, its `createdby` in your case) and the date (converted from the timestamp value)
2. Aggregate with `MIN` and `MAX` functions.

In case the the last attendee value could be `CHECK_IN` and the first one could be `CHECK_OUT`, you can add the `FILTER` clause as demonstrated below, to filter the `MIN`/`MAX` inputs only for the relevant attendee records:

```
SELECT
    createdby,
    check_date::date,
    MIN(check_date) FILTER (WHERE attendee = 'CHECK_IN') as check_in,
    MAX(check_date) FILTER (WHERE attendee = 'CHECK_OUT') as check_out
FROM mytable
GROUP BY createdby, check_date::date
```

Comment: thanks @S-Man both for the answer and provided examples. I will check as soon as possible

Comment: @irvandi Did this help? Please don't forget to UPVOTE any helpful answer. This honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your problem. If one answer solves your problem, please ACCEPT it additionally to close the question.